# Sass watch command compiles .scss files before full sftp upload

Tags: sass, sftp, watch, winscp

I use WinSCP to download and edit `.scss` files and sass on Linux (on the server) to compile them to `.css`.

After saving the file, I use: `sass scss/style.scss css/style.css`, which successfully replaces the css file with the compiled sccs.

**The problem**

I want to skip the part where I return to the command line after editing the scss file, for the sake of automation and saving time.

But, if I use the `watch` command: `sass --watch scss/style.scss:css/style.css` to synchronize the two files, alerts about nonexistent css errors pop up:

```
Change detected to: scss/style.scss
      error scss/style.scss (Line 232: Invalid CSS after "...ht: bold; line-": expected "{", was "")
```

**Note that** when the file uploads quicker than usual (sometimes it happens) the watch command does its job, with no errors.

This is because, when the file upload takes time, sass compiles the scss file (on the server) before it is fully uploaded to the remote folder. Thus, it only compiles part of the file, resulting in css errors.

Is there a way to set a timer to the watch command so that it waits a few seconds after it detects changes and before compiling?

Any other way to overcome this is, of course, accepted!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the one in a billion facing the same problem (I know you are out there), time to answer to my tumbleweed:

The Solution is simple

**Do the exact opposite:**

1. [Install ruby and then sass](http://sass-lang.com/install) on your pc.
2. Tell sass to watch for changes between scss/css files locally with:`sass --watch scss/style.scss:css/style.css`
3. Set WinSCP local dir on the css folder which is watched by sass.
4. Set the WinSCP remote dir on the css folder you want to edit.
5. Set WinSCP to keep remote dir up to date from the ***Commands > Keep remote directory up to date*** menu.

That's it.

If you edit and save your local scss file, sass will compile it into css, then WinSCP will detect the change on the css and automatically upload it to the remote folder.